# How to check which TLS protocol my app is using for network operation

Tags: java, android, ssl, tls1.2

I have query regarding TLS in android.There is need in my project to ensure that every device is using only TLS 1.2 for any kind of network operation.As  some payment gateway has already made it mandate to allow calls only from TLS 1.2.

```
SSLParameters sslParameters;
try {
    sslParameters = SSLContext.getDefault()
            .getDefaultSSLParameters();
} catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
    // ...
}
```

using above code i can know how many protocols is enable in my device.
E.g=In my device it's showing 3 protocols-:

tls 1.0,tls 1.1 and tls 1.2

My concern is how can i ensure that network call going from the device is using tls 1.2.

Is there is any code to check which protocol is my device using for the network call.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the protocol after the fact from the `SSLSession`, but what you should really be doing is pre-emptively disabling all TLS protocols *except* TLSv1.2, which you can do ahead of the fact, via the, err, `SSLParameters`.